# Redirect loop with ASP.NET Core website running under Google Cloud Run

Tags: asp.net-core, google-cloud-run

When my ASP.NET (Core) 6.0 website is deployed to Google Cloud Run, I hit a redirect loop when I try to login.

I have removed the call that registers the global RequireHttpsAttribute filter because, when deployed, SSL is not terminated by Kestrel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the controller that handles my login page also had its own explicit `[RequireHttps]` decorated!!

Silly problem/solution that I am posting here to help others.